# Do <link href=""> tags only go in the <head> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible/good practice to use `<link href"">` to include stylesheets outside of the `<head>` tag, or do they only work / should they be only used in `<head>`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible to do it.

It's not recommended to do it, because whatever content comes before the `<link>` will start rendering and then when the stylesheet is loaded will be rerendered with the new styles.  That means that the pageload will be slower (because the browser has to redo all that work) and uglier (because there will be this flash of content with one style that's then restyled to look different).

Comment: However it does not conform w3c specification

Comment: Sure.  The question of what's "possible" and what's "valid" are totally different questions!

Comment: It is OK in HTML 5; `<link rel="stylesheet">` is body-ok: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/links.html#sec-link-types

Answer (score 7):

They are invalid outside of `head`, though no browser I know of won't apply the styles if not a child of `head`.

Answer (score 5):

> The  tag defines the
>   relationship between a document and an
>   external resource.
>
> The  tag is most used to link to
>   style sheets.
>
> **Note: The link element must be embedded in the head section, and it
>   can appear any number of times.**

From: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

> **The LINK element `(<link>)` is used to add external information related to the HTML document in the header of
>   your document in the HEAD element.**

From: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/use-links

Comment: I added a W3C reference as an alternative

Comment: w3schools should be the last place you cite for a reference about HTML practice.

Comment: Also the statement that all `link` types are only allowed in `head` is wrong for HTML5.

Answer (score 5):

According to the HTML 4.01 spec, the `<link>` tag must appear in the head section:

> This element defines a link. Unlike A, it may only appear in the HEAD section of a document, although it may appear any number of times. Although LINK has no content, it conveys relationship information that may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways (e.g., a tool-bar with a drop-down menu of links).

Source W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-LINK

Answer (score 4):

The `<link>` tag does not define structure of a webpage, so it should stay out of the `<body>` and `<footer>`.

I can't think of any reason why you would ever want/need to put it anywhere other than the `<head>`

Comment: I'm using a javascript datepicker only on 1 page, and need to include its css only for that page, all my pages share a header template so if I put it in `<head>` it would be loaded on every page

Comment: That's an inheritance problem. There should be a better workaround than using Meta tags in your structure. Maybe you need to reconfigure the way your templates load so that you can add head code to individual pages if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, it is valid for specifically link type `"stylesheet"` to go within `body` element, as from https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#linkTypes it is *body-ok*.

Note: `html` is only permitted to contain two elements, `head` followed by`body`. However if you put `link` right under `html`, the standard regrettably allows this in some situations as it allows omitting `<head>` and `<body>` start and end tags in some situations. This is due to crappy legacy pages and you should never do this.

Summary: Just put your `link` in `head`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,  element is metadata element, whose permitted parent is head, or a  element in head.