# Load css from handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am using ember js. How do I load a css style sheet from a handlebars js template

For example this doesn't work

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/about.css"}}
    // HTML CONTENT
    .......
</script>
```

Comment: Try fixing the }} at the end of the <link line. If that doesn't work, you may need to load the css using javascript.

Comment: `link` tags should always be placed in the `head` of the DOM (per W3C recommendation). If you need to split apart your stylesheet, I suggest using controllers to trigger view methods that manage the stylesheets. I can see the appeal of just putting a stylesheet into a hbs template, but it may produce unwanted effects for some of your visitors.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewBlancarte I would appreciate a jsfiddle. Not quite got my head around views yet.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte also what side effects?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5828365/614152

Comment: @david_adler Is there a particular reason that you'd like to split apart your stylesheets? It would be better (both for performance and using valid DOM structure) to precompile them all into one file and just serve it on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it works to me.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="color">
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  The color of the day is: {{color}}
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/162/edit