# how to reduce div size in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a login page, the screenshot is below.

http://prntscr.com/2pksiq

Where as i want the output as http://prntscr.com/2pga73 . I am trying to reduce the size of the tags

`<div id="logo" class="logo col-xs-2"></div>`

`<div id="title" class="page-title green-bg col-xs-8">Local Adventures</div>`

I am new to CSS, please suggest me a way to fix this. I am using twitter bootstrap in my project.

I have the below HTML:

```
<div class="visible-xs stop-detail">    


<head>

    <link href="C:/L.A project/local-adventure/web/src/main/webapp/resources/components/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/L.A project/local-adventure/web/src/main/webapp/resources/components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="C:/L.A project/local-adventure/web/src/main/webapp/resources/localadventures/css/createaccount.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="C:/L.A project/local-adventure/web/src/main/webapp/resources/localadventures/css/styles.css"rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css' />
    <link href="C:/L.A project/local-adventure/web/src/main/webapp/resources/localadventures/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Local-Adventures</title>


            <div id="login-form">
            <div class="logo col-xs-4"></div>
            <div class="page-title green-bg col-xs-8">Local Adventures</div>

            <a href="#">Create an Account</a>
            <a href="#">Sign In</a>
              <input type="email" required value="Email Address" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email Address'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email Address')this.value='' ">
              <input type="email" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' ">
              <input type="email" required value="Confirm password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Confirm password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Confirm password')this.value='' ">

        <br><br>
        <span class='btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'>Create An Account</span>
        <span class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>Facebook Login</span>

    </div> <!-- end login-form -->

    </div>
```

My CSS is below:

```
   @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* ---------- GENERAL ---------- */
/*
body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #999;
    font: 100%/1.5em sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
*/


a {
    color: #2a2a2a;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:1px 33;
}

a:hover { color: #88c425; }

fieldset {
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn-success {
 border-radius:0px;
 background-color: #88c425
}

.btn-success:hover {
background-color: #88c425
}

.btn-primary {
 border-radius:0px;
}

input {
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="submit"] { cursor: pointer; }

.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table; 
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

/* ---------- LOGIN-FORM ---------- */

#login-form {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 300px;
}

#login-form h3 {
    background-color: #79a002;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#login-form fieldset {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 -1px -1px;
    padding: 0px;

}

#login-form fieldset:before {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 8px;
}

#login-form input {
    font-size: 14px;
}

#login-form input[type="email"], #login-form input[type="password"] {
    border:none; /* clear previous borders */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88c425; /* add bottom border */
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

#login-form input[type="email"] {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#login-form input[type="password"] {
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}

#login-form input[type="submit"] {
    background: #1dabb8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}
```

Comment: All your stylesheets and javascripts files should be linked in the `<head>`

Comment: I need to make this login screen as responsive, so i was told to remove the <hea>, <html>, <body> tags.

Comment: Responsive design doesnt mean that you dont follow specifications for web design. The way that you are doing this will cause your web page to load slower because it will have to re-render the page with the correct CSS. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828365/do-link-href-tags-only-go-in-the-head-tag

Comment: I read the link posted by you. I have a global html page, where i have all the style sheets and javascript files in the <head> tag. Do you still think i should have them in my html file as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Bootstrap, you had configurate before download it your GRID
It seems do be like a 12 Grid.

you used :

```
<div id="title" class="page-title green-bg col-xs-8">Local Adventures</div>
```

it should be :

```
<div id="title" class="page-title green-bg col-xs-4">Local Adventures</div>
```

you take 8 pieces from a 12 piece cake, so its larger. just take the half and you will get the same width you want for.

And please, if you use a mighty framework like bootstrap, dont overwrite its own classes with ids or something, its bad practise!

Comment: did you changed the idea from "stackErr", to put all your links and meta information in a <head> tag ? and make sure that your tag with the class row only contains the cols you want in. One row = 12 cols (your grid !) and make sure, that no class or ID overwrite the bootstrap class, so delete the id "title" from your div, i think its overwrite in any case.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your bootstrap is overriding your css? Try putting important at the end:

```
#title{
    width: 400px !important;
    height: 90px !important;
}
```

Comment: Using `!important` is a hack. There are better ways to override styles. Read: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: @stackErr - it's no more of a hack than the rest of the CSS.